# Not able to start Jboss Server on run.bat

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when I run the JBoss Server using run.bat.

[image]
[image]

**Updated**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set to a `JDK`. Your screen shot shows a `JRE` for the JAVA_HOME. Switch that to a JDK and re-try starting JBoss.

Also the JAVA_HOME should be in your PATH environment variable.

Alternatively you can manually set the JAVA_HOME in the `run.conf.bat` file

Comment: You mean (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34) that? Should I also include \bin ?

Comment: Also make sure you have JAVA_HOME in your PATH variable.

Comment: So, %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34  - Like that?

Comment: May be. I don't know a lot about windows configurations. Basically you want JBoss to find a compatible Java JDK in the PATH. If you do echo $PATH, does it show the JDK in the path?

Comment: Is JBoss still complaining about JAVA_HOME not being set? Can you try setting it in your current shell (e.g. SET JAVA_HOME=....)?

Comment: @AppSensei - see this [windows-java-home-problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229019/windows-java-home-problems) on how to set it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

your java path is not set to jdk and you have to configure java path in as java_home in standalone.conf.bat
and start with run.bat

Comment: Your answer seems to be just a duplicate of the accepted 9-year-old answer.